# How to get Surface of SurfaceView

Tags: java, android

How do you get the surface used by a SurfaceView in android? I have looked at the the documentation, but there is no method that returns a surface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [SurfaceView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView):

> Access to the underlying surface is provided via the SurfaceHolder interface, which can be retrieved by calling [`getHolder()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView#getHolder()).

From the SurfaceHolder, simply invoke [`getSurface()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder#getSurface()) to obtain the Surface.

In Kotlin:

```kt
surfaceView.holder.surface
```

Comment: hope this helps.